# Want to set li innerHTML of ul

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a javascript function where I get a `ul` object from my HTML and want to set the text of one of the `li elements in the`ul`. I'm doing:

```
list = document.getElementById('list_name');
```

Then I want to access the ith `li` element of list using a loop.
I have:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    list[i].innerHTML = "<a>text</a>"; 
}
```

but this is not working. What is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to access the child `li` elements of the `ul`. JavaScript and the DOM API can't automagically do that for you.

```
var list = document.getElementById('list_name'),
    items = list.childNodes;

for (var i = 0, length = childNodes.length; i < length; i++)
{
    if (items[i].nodeType != 1) {
       continue;
    }
    items[i].innerHTML = "<a>text</a>"; 
}
```

You *could* also use `getElementsByTagName('li')` but it will get *all* descendent `li` elements, and it seems you want only the direct descendants.

You could also avoid `innerHTML` if you want.

```
var a = document.createElement('a'),
    text = document.createTextNode('text');

a.appendChild(text);
items[i].appendChild(a);
```

`innerHTML` can cause issues, such as lost event handlers and the performance issue of serialising and re-parsing the HTML structure. This should be negligible in your example, however.

Comment: You'll want to use an if block for `items[i].nodeType === 1` in your loop to avoid text nodes. Don't forget to append the anchor tag in your second example.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery Sample code, although the others work:

```
$("#list_name li").text("<a href=''>text</a>");
```

Its much more succinct with jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

```
var el = document.createElement("li"),
    content = document.createTextNode("My sample text"),
    myUl = document.getElementById("ulOne");

el.appendChild(content);
el.id = "bar";

myUl.appendChild(el);
```

Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x32j00h5/

Answer (score -2):

I prefer a aproach using getElemenetByTagName, if somehow you  get a extra node like a script tag or a span you will have problems. A guess this code will help you:

```
var list = document.getElementById("mylist");
var items = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
for(var i = 0, size = items.length; i< size; i++){
    items[i].innerHTML = "<a href='#'>LINK</a>";
}
```

Comment: You will have non valid HTML if you have a `span` as a child of a `ul`.